# CustomPouchError 409 Conflict Document Update Conflict

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, pouchdb

I'm not too good with Promises (first time working with them).  With some other help, I've modified the code some, but I'm still getting a 409 conflict error on the putAttachment() method in the readFileThenAttach() method.  So, I need another set of eyes to look at this for me.  I had been consistently getting this error, then I come in this morning and tried it again.  It worked twice (I didn't get the error).  I stopped the program then when I ran it again, I got the error again.  I'm not sure what's wrong.  The revisions seem to be okay, so I'm not sure if its some timing issue or what with how the Promises are in my code.  The execution path of this code begins in the importProject() method and from there importInspectionPhotos() is called.  Can someone take a look to see if they can see anything that stands out?  Thanks.

```
function buildReinspectionLinks(db: InspectionDb) {
    return db.allObservations()
        .then(([points, lines]) => {
            let observations = new Map([...points, ...lines]
                .filter(obs => (<any>obs).access_original)
                .map<[string, Observation]>(obs => [(<any>obs).access_id, obs]))
            let changed = new Set()
            for (let obs of observations.values()) {
                let doc = (<any>obs).access_original
                if (doc.Inspect_ID != doc.Original_ID) {
                    let reinspected = observations.get(doc.Original_ID)
                    doc.reinspected_id = reinspected._id
                    reinspected.reinspected = true
                    if (!reinspected.reinspection_ids) {
                        reinspected.reinspection_ids = []
                    }
                    reinspected.reinspection_ids.push(obs._id)
                    changed.add(obs)
                    changed.add(reinspected)
                }
            }
            // TODO: Recurse the relationships?
            return Promise.all([...changed].map(obs => db.post(obs)))
        })
}

function importInspectionPhotos(db: InspectionDb, directoryBase: string) {

const observations = db.allObservations().then(([points, lines]) => new Map([...points, ...lines].filter(obs => (<any>obs).access_original).map<[string, Observation]>(obs => [(<any>obs).access_id, obs])))
const filenames = globP("**/*.{jpg, jpeg, gif, png}", { cwd: directoryBase })

return Promise.all([observations, filenames]).then(([obs, names]: [Map<string, Observation>, string[]]) => {

    const fileObservations: FileObservation[] = names.map(file => {
        const filename = basename(file)
        const accessID = getAccessObservationId(filename)
        return {
            file,
            path: `${directoryBase}/${file}`,
            observation: obs.get(accessID)
        } as FileObservation
    }).filter((fileOb: FileObservation) => !!fileOb.observation)

    return fileObservations.reduce((lastPromise, fileOb) => lastPromise.then(() => readFileThenAttach(db, fileOb)), Promise.resolve())
  })
}

function getAccessObservationId(filename: string): string {

return filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('_'))
}

function readFileThenAttach(db: InspectionDb, fileOb: FileObservation): Promise<any> {

return readFileP(fileOb.path)
    .then((data: Buffer) => blobUtil.arrayBufferToBlob(data.buffer, contentType(extname(fileOb.path))))
    .then(blob => ({ content_type: blob.type, data: blob }) as PouchAttachment)
    .then(pa => db.putAttachment(fileOb.observation._id, (fileOb.observation as any)._rev, fileOb.filename, pa.data, pa.content_type))
    .then(update => ((fileOb.observation as any)._rev = update.rev))
}

function importData(filename: string, db: InspectionDb, table: string, importer: (db: InspectionDb, doc: any) => Promise<any>) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let trader = spawn(TraderPath, ['select', `-f="${filename}"`, `-t=${table}`])

    trader.stderr.on('data', reject)
    trader.on('error', reject)

    let outstream = []
    trader.stdout.on('data', data => outstream.push(data))

    var imports = []
    trader.on('close', code => {
        if (code > 0) reject('Trader returned non-zero exit code')
        safeLoadAll(''.concat(...outstream), (doc: any) => imports.push(importer(db, doc))) // safeLoadAll is synchronous
        Promise.all(imports).then(resolve)
    })
})
}

export function importProject(filename: string, project_id: string) {
let db: InspectionDb

return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {        
        db = new InspectionDb(project_id)

        return Promise.all([
            importData(filename, db, 'Project_Inspections', importInspection),
            importData(filename, db, 'Inspection', importObservation),
        ])
    })
    .then(() => buildReinspectionLinks(db))
    .then(() => importInspectionPhotos(db, join(dirname(filename), '../Inspection_Projects')))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this ended up being very simple and silly.  The PouchDB typings in the project was wrong...it had the rev and filename parameters for putAttachment() reversed...filename should have been first then rev.  Changing this corrected the issue.

Comment: Wow that was hard to find! This still hasn't been fixed in the @typings lib.